# Problem with recursive enums in Swift 5.1

Tags: swift, xcode, enums, console, lldb

I'm learning recursive enums in Swift 5.1 with Swift documentation.

Here is a code.

```
indirect enum ArithmeticExpression {
    case number(Int)
    case addition(ArithmeticExpression, ArithmeticExpression)
    case multiplication(ArithmeticExpression, ArithmeticExpression)

    func evaluate(_ expression: ArithmeticExpression) -> Int {
        switch expression {
        case let .number(value):
            return value
        case let .addition(left, right):
            return evaluate(left) + evaluate(right)
        case let .multiplication(left, right):
            return evaluate(left) * evaluate(right)
        }
    }
}

let five = ArithmeticExpression.number(5)
let four = ArithmeticExpression.number(4)
let sum = ArithmeticExpression.addition(five, four)
let product = ArithmeticExpression.multiplication(sum, ArithmeticExpression.number(2))

print(ArithmeticExpression.evaluate(product))
```

[image: Screen]

I think something is going wrong in the last line of code.

What does that mean?

Comment: *Hint:* Read about the difference between static (type) methods and instance methods.

Comment: The console is not printing `lldb_expr_5`. The console prints `(Function)` according to your screenshot.

Comment: The lldb_expr_5 is the name of the swift module that the Playground is building your code into.  Swift code has to exist in a module, so the Playground (and the REPL) has to come up with a name for it and we chose lldb_expr...  The 5 is because each "submission" of code in the Playground compiles into a different module.  That's to help us handle redefinitions, which is useful to allow in Playground & REPL but is disallowed in a single module.  The module name is part of the full name of the class, which is why you are seeing it in this output.  It isn't relevant to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`evaluate(_:)` is an *instance function* of `ArithmeticExpression`, i.e. you have to call it *on* an instance of `ArithmeticExpression` (with that instance being what `self` refers to). The type of `evaluate(_:)` is `(ArithmeticExpression) -> Int`.

Swift lets you call instance functions on types. What you get back is an *unbound instance function*. That is to say, a function with no value bound as its `self` value yet. That's what you're doing when you run `ArithmeticExpression.evaluate` on its own. The unbound instance function that you get back has the type:

```
(ArithmeticExpression) -> (ArithmetricExpression) -> Int
// ^---  the "self"        ^--- the "expression" param ^--- the final return value.
```

By calling it and providing `product` as an argument (`ArithmeticExpression.evaluate(product)`), what you get back is a function of type `(ArithmeticExpression) -> Int`. This function is a *bound instance function*, i.e. `self` is now bound (it now has the value of `product`), but it's awaiting to be called yet again, with another `ArithmeticExpression` as an argument.

There's two ways to solve this to achieve what you want:

1. Either make this a static function. A static function isn't called on an instance, it's called directly on the type, as you tried to do:

   ```
   indirect enum ArithmeticExpression {
       case number(Int)
       case addition(ArithmeticExpression, ArithmeticExpression)
       case multiplication(ArithmeticExpression, ArithmeticExpression)

       // Make it static here
       static func evaluate(_ expression: ArithmeticExpression) -> Int {
           switch expression {
           case let .number(value):
               return value
           case let .addition(left, right):
               return evaluate(left) + evaluate(right)
           case let .multiplication(left, right):
               return evaluate(left) * evaluate(right)
           }
       }
   }

   let five = ArithmeticExpression.number(5)
   let four = ArithmeticExpression.number(4)
   let sum = ArithmeticExpression.addition(five, four)
   let product = ArithmeticExpression.multiplication(sum, ArithmeticExpression.number(2))

   print(ArithmeticExpression.evaluate(product))
   ```
2. Keep `evaluate` as an instance function, but call it directly on the instance your want to evaluate, rather than on the type. Since `self` would be the expression you're interested in, you no longer need the `expression` parameter:

   ```
   indirect enum ArithmeticExpression {
       case number(Int)
       case addition(ArithmeticExpression, ArithmeticExpression)
       case multiplication(ArithmeticExpression, ArithmeticExpression)

       func evaluate() -> Int {
           switch self {
           case let .number(value):
               return value
           case let .addition(left, right):
               return left.evaluate() + right.evaluate()
           case let .multiplication(left, right):
               return left.evaluate() * right.evaluate()
           }
       }
   }

   let five = ArithmeticExpression.number(5)
   let four = ArithmeticExpression.number(4)
   let sum = ArithmeticExpression.addition(five, four)
   let product = ArithmeticExpression.multiplication(sum, ArithmeticExpression.number(2))

   print(product.evaluate())
   ```

   I would say this is probably the more "idiomatic" version.

Comment: Like | product.evaluate(product) | ?

Comment: @Sam You *could* do that, but it would be pointless. Either pass `product` as `self` (by making `evaluate` an instance function, and calling it on the instance `product`), or pass it as the parameter, but don't do both. By the way, you can use `back ticks to format code like this`